# Retroactively see what's taking up RAM/CPU on a window server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I seem to have issues with processes taking up a lot of CPU/RAM in the middle of the night on my Windows Server 2012r2/2008r2 boxes when I'm sleeping, so I was wondering if there was an automated way to gather the pid, processname, and maybe the command line value (since iis worker processes only show up as w3wp.exe) whenever the CPU or RAM is at 90% usage or higher for a certain period of time?

Preferably any solution should consume as little overhead as possible, since the boxes would already be in a bad state when the solution needs to act, and since I need the boxes to continue to serve websites in the meantime.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You could set up a user defined Data Collector Set in Performance Monitor and schedule it to run during the time period when you typically experience this issue. Then review the Data Collector Set report.

Comment: @joeqwerty Sounds like a pretty good answer to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a user defined Data Collector Set in Performance Monitor and schedule it to run during the time period when you typically experience this issue. Then review the Data Collector Set report.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bit of a hack in case you couldn't get what you want from process monitor:

Run a PowerShell script on a schedule, every 5 minutes perhaps, that would get the processes consuming greater than a certain amount of resources, and output that to a file. You could review the file in the AM (even email it to yourself) and see what stands out.

*If that sounds useful, let me know and I can post something when I'm next at my desk*